# Problemas usando React Context

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Estive estudando React e desenvolvendo um app, mas tenho um problema quando tento usar `context`. Em um componente, eu crio o contexto e forneço seu valor, mas quando tento usar o valor atual do contexto em outro componente, tenho o valor padrão. Código:

```js
export const OwnerInformationContext = React.createContext({})

function NameChoose() {

   ...
   const [ownerInformation,setOwnerInformation] = useState({})
 
    function onpressSubmitButton(e : FormEvent) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
        setOwnerInformation({name:'name',roomId:'id',owner:'true'})
    }

    return(
        <div className="page-container">
            <OwnerInformationContext.Provider value={ownerInformation} />
            ...
                <form onSubmit={onpressSubmitButton}>
                    ...
                </form>
            ...
    );
}

export default NameChoose;
```

-> No componente acima, o defino e no abaixo tento usá-lo:

```js
import { OwnerInformationContext } from '../NameChoose/index'

    function ComponentTwo(){

    const consumeOwnerContext = useContext(OwnerInformationContext)

    useEffect(() => {
                console.log(consumeOwnerContext)
        }, [])

    return <h1>test</h1>

    }
```

Porém, só consigo ter acesso ao valor padrão, que é `{}`

Comment: entendeu o exemplo?

Comment: entendi sim, valeu

Comment: Só uma questão: se eu quisesse que o `ComponentTwo` tivesse acesso as variáveis do `NameChoose`, mas que não renderizasse nele, teria algum hook que eu poderia usar ?

Comment: Não tem como, se o estado for local é somente do próprio componente! se o estado é para todos tem que ser Redux ou Context Api.

Comment: E também não tem muita lógica que você relatou! se está iniciando talvez precise entender mais a lógica do processo, o que você deseja fazer? talvez há caminhos melhores, quase com certeza que há!

Comment: É pq tipo, esse component `NameChoose` é para escolha de nome do usuário e outras definições, ai queria pegar essas configurações e passar para o `ComponentTwo `, porém, já faço isso pelo backend com socket ou então com o sessionStorage, mas gostaria de saber se tinha alguma forma de fazer por hooks, mas pelo visto não há,enfim, obrigado pela atenção!!

Comment: Coloca tudo no ContextApi essa parte das definições de usuário e utilize nos componentes! é assim que faz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código está totalmente errado, porque, quando se cria um [React.Context](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) significa que deseja que vários componentes compartilhe do mesmo estado, da mesma funções, etc. Para que isso funcione, é criado um ***Contexto*** e um ***Provedor*** que envolve todos os componentes que precisam utilizar o mesmo código, exemplo mínimo:

```js
const CounterContext = React.createContext();
const CounterProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = 
    React.useState(0);
  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={{counter, setCounter}}>
      {children}
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  )
}


const View1 = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(CounterContext);
  return (
    <div>{context.counter}</div>
  )
}

const View2 = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(CounterContext);
  const handleIncrement = () 
    => context.setCounter(state => state + 1);
  const handleDecrement = () 
    => context.setCounter(state => state - 1);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>Incrementar</button>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>Decrementar</button>
    </div>
  )
}
const View3 = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(CounterContext);
  return (
    <div>{context.counter}</div>
  )
}
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <CounterProvider>
      <View1 />
      <View2 />
      <View3 />
    </CounterProvider>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <Root/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Foi criado um código de um simples contador e uma função para mudar o valor desse contador, 3 componentes `View` que compartilham do mesmo estado porque estão envolvidos pelo `Provider` criado.

<sup>Referencias:</sup>

- [React.Context](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- [React.Provider](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider)

Observação: além da sua montagem está errada, o seu código está muito mau organizado, isso são fatores importantes mesmo que você seja um iniciante, então preste atenção de não criar um código de formulário por exemplo diretamente dentro do `Provider`, não é usual e no seu código causou muitos problemas.