# Obter Token de acesso apos login - React + Axios

Tags: react, axios

Estou tentando setar globalmente o token com base na resposta da função login. Anteriormente recebia na reposta a informação do token, mas agora, não mais... Acessando as ferramentas do desenvolvedor, aba Network do Chrome, vejo que a informação esta la. Porém, se utilizo o `console.log(resp)`, falta informação.

```
function login(login) {
    axios
      .post("/login", login)
      .then((resp) => {
        setValidateToken(resp.headers.authorization);
        setStatusResponse(resp.status);
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
          resp.headers.authorization;
      })
      .catch(() => alert("Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe invalide!"));
  }
```

Reposta do Axios:

```
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config:
adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
baseURL: "*******"
data: "{"email":"*******","password":"******"}"
headers:
Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
__proto__: Object
maxBodyLength: -1
maxContentLength: -1
method: "post"
timeout: 0
transformRequest: [ƒ]
transformResponse: [ƒ]
url: "/login"
validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus(status)
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
__proto__: Object
data: ""
headers:
cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
content-length: "0"
expires: "0"
pragma: "no-cache"
__proto__: Object
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: você está usando o estado local do componente, então, quando entra no outro componente se perde esse valor. Deve nesse caso usar ContextApi ou Redux para armazenar e recuperar globalmente utilizando isso em todos os componentes se assim for necessário.

Comment: Um exemplo que eu mesmo implementei: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/476140/problemas-usando-react-context/476150#476150

Comment: o estado local eu uso somente p/ validar o login, apos o redirecionamento, eu seto o token globalmente no axios.

Comment: No final das contas o problema estava no backend e nao na funcao que fiz... obrigado.