# Passar função pra outro componente - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho uma função que muda um estado, só que preciso receber essa função em outro componente e aplicar no botão que vai executar a função. Quando coloco um botão nesse mesmo componente, consigo executar a função de mudar o tema da página. Mas o problema é que o botão de mudar o tema tem que ser em outro componente.

```
function App() {
  
  const [theme , setTheme] = useState(false)
  const mudarTema = () => {
    
    theme === false ? setTheme(true) : setTheme(false)
  }
 

  return (
   

    <>

    <div className="App" >
    
     {theme && <Light />  }
    <Rotas />
   
    </div>
    
    <Footer />
   
    </>
  )
}

export default App


onde o botão está: 


export const Header = () => {

  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false)
  const [hidenav , setHideNav] = useState(true)


  return(
   
   <header className="header" >
   
    {hidenav && 
       <nav className="nav" >
     
       
          <div className="logo"><Link to="/">
            <img src={Logo} />
            </Link></div>

            <button  >MUDAR TEMA</button>
            <BotaoTema />


             <button className="botao-menu">
              <GiHamburgerMenu onClick={() => {setShowMenu(true); setHideNav(false)} }  />
             </button> 
     
       </nav>
       }
```

..... cortei o restante do código, pra facilitar a leitura, pois o botão é aí onde tá escrito "MUDAR TEMA"

Answer (score 0):

Na minha visão você deve utilizar [Context](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html), [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) ou algo que planeje seu código a executar funções de mudança de ***estado global***, por exemplo, mudança da cor do site inteira. [Um exemplo claro está nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/476140/problemas-usando-react-context/476150#476150) utilizando `context`. Como funciona, ao criar esse `context` ele vai estabelecer relação com todos os componentes que estão internamente declarados e com isso tendo a possibilidade em compartilhar de forma clara variáveis e funcionalidades globais.

Um exemplo claro de mudança de cor do fundo do seu site:

```js
const CssContext = React.createContext();
const CssProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("#d3d3d3");
  const handleChangeColor = () => {
    if (color === "#d3d3d3") {
      setColor("#FFFF00");
    } else {
      setColor("#d3d3d3");
    }
  }
  return (
    <CssContext.Provider value={{color, handleChangeColor}}>
      {children}
    </CssContext.Provider>
  )
}
const Page = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(CssContext);
  return <div style={{backgroundColor: context.color}}>{context.color}</div>
}
const Button = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(CssContext);
  return <div>
    <button onClick={context.handleChangeColor}>Alterar Cor</button>
  </div>
}
const Button1 = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(CssContext);
  return <div>
    <button onClick={context.handleChangeColor}>Alterar Cor</button>
  </div>
}
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <CssProvider>
      <Page />      
      <Button />
      <Button1 />
    </CssProvider>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <Root/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

---

Observe que os componentes estão executando a mesma função `Button` e `Button1` e esse exemplo denota que todos os componentes que estão dentro desse Contexto tem a possibilidade de compartilhar a mesma funções, esse tipo de código geralmente em Login de usuário para armazenar token ou dados pertinentes ao todo o seu código pode ser criado.

Existe outro exemplo de compartilhamento via `props`, mas, com ressalvas porque se for para algum componente interno até é utilizando mas, se isso for refletir para vários outros não é a melhor forma de fazer esse código, mas, vou deixar como exemplo para estudos:

```js
function App(props) {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("#d3d3d3");
  function handleState() {
    if (color === "#d3d3d3") {
      setColor("#FFFF00");
    } else {
      setColor("#d3d3d3");
    }
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div style={{backgroundColor: color}}>{color}</div>
      <Button handleState={handleState}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
function Button(props) {
  return (<button onClick={props.handleState}>Mudar</button>);
}
function Root () {
  return (
    <div>
      <App />      
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render( <Root/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Então vai depender da sua estratégia, essas duas formas são bem utilizadas, mas, precisa planejar.

<sup>Referencias:</sup>

- [React.Context](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- [React.Provider](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider)